# pd.to_numeric() returns TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Tags: python, pandas

On a given dataframe I'm creating a new column based on values from different columns and another dataframe.

code that creates the new column:

```py
df['normalized_value'] = df.apply(lambda x:
                                      x['value'] / rates_df.loc[rates_df['date'] == x['date'], 'EUR']
                                      if
                                      x['currency'] != 'EUR'
                                      else
                                      x['value'],
                                      axis=1)
```

after the column is created it looks like this:

```
0        45500
1        32500
2        25000
3        33000
5        19000
         ...  
61790    60000
61791    57000
61792    50999
61793    66500
61794    67000
Name: normalized_value, Length: 59951, dtype: object
```

I then try to convert it to float type using the following code:

```py
df['normalized_value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['normalized_price'])
```

The following error is returned:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please show us what is in `df['normalized_price']` after the apply call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation it turns out the problem was in the application's underlying code.

The external dataframe (`rates_df`) did not contain some of the required data and for some reason it returned a string instead of throwing an error. This caused some of the values in `df['normalized_value']` to be actual strings containing the actual type of the value it was expecting.

Once the problem with `rates_df` was solved the convertion took place without any problems.